# How to execute this code when error is lowest?

Tags: python

In this work, I wrote a code. There are 3 points, and y(4th point) is the point which is the point sum of euclidean minimum to other 3 points.
Firt I wrote it to work for first 50 iterations. It works perfect. And it finds the right y point.
But I want it to work when, |yi+1 - yi| is higher than "error(in this case I choose it 10**-5)" value.

> |yi+1 - yi| =>> euclidean distance between last and current
> iteration

Here is my code;

"e" is the last iteration. But "e" updates(equals to current iteration) everytime when program exits "for loops". So in 2nd iteration "eps" equals to "0" and my code executes. I can not understand why :(

```
import math as m

a = ([1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
     [20.0, 18.0, 25.0],
     [10.0, 12.0, 42.0])

y = ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
x = ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

r = 0
t = 0

e = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0]
eps = 10

while (eps > 10**-5):

  for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
      c = (a[j][i]/(m.sqrt((a[j][0]-y[0])**2+(a[j][1]-y[1])**2+(a[j][2]-y[2])**2)))
  
      b = 1/(m.sqrt((a[j][0]-y[0])**2+(a[j][1]-y[1])**2+(a[j][2]-y[2])**2))
     
      r += c
      t += b 
      
    x[i] = r/t
    r = 0
    t = 0 
  y = x
  eps = (m.sqrt((y[0]-e[0])**2+(y[1]-e[1])**2+(y[2]-e[2])**2))
  e = y
  print("y= ", y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Thanks for -1. You helped a lot.

```
import math as m

a = ([1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
     [20.0, 18.0, 25.0],
     [10.0, 12.0, 42.0])


def euclideanminpoint(a): 
  y = ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
  x = ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

  r = 0
  t = 0

  e = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0]
  eps = 10
  k = 0
  while (eps > 10**-5):
    
    for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
        c = (a[j][i]/(m.sqrt((a[j][0]-y[0])**2+(a[j][1]-y[1])**2+(a[j][2]-y[2])**2)))
  
        b = 1/(m.sqrt((a[j][0]-y[0])**2+(a[j][1]-y[1])**2+(a[j][2]-y[2])**2))
     
        r += c
        t += b 
      
      x[i] = r/t
      r = 0
      t = 0 
    
    y = x
    eps = (m.sqrt((y[0]-e[0])**2+(y[1]-e[1])**2+(y[2]-e[2])**2))
    for i in range(3):
      e[i] = y[i]
    k += 1
    print("i= ","y= ","\n", k, y)

euclideanminpoint(a)
```